# CSS div being cut off

Tags: css, scroll

I have a sidebar that is fixed along the side of a text document.  The contents of the sidebar are a fixed size content submission form and below that is a list of submitted content.  Naturally, I would like the submitted content to be scrollable, so I have overflow set to auto; however, when I resize the screen to a lower size, the div that the content is contained in is cut off and the last few objects are lost.

Currently the sidebar is fixed and height is 100%, the submission form height is 300 px and the content list height is 70%

```
#sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
}

#sidebarUL{ /*this is the submission list*/
  height:70%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#draggable{
  /*height here depends on content ready for submission, though it is absolute; 400px etc*/
}
```

Comment: overflow:scroll; is to make scroll-able div content, and can you elaborate more, or show an example?

Comment: @pal-singh looks like you posted the answer... if you'd posted it in the "anwser" box instead of as a comment, it'd be more clear for the rest of us.

Comment: i had posted it as answer, you can mark it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use overflow:scroll; to get the scrollbar in your div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: yeah, the only problem i run into is when resizing the window. the margin between the bottom of the window and the scroll bar decreases until the end of the scrollable div is off the screen.